# GitHub GraphQL search limited to language

Tags: github, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

I'm trying to use GitHub's GraphQL API to find a list of repos matching a query but limited to a specific language. However I can't find anything in the docs relating to the language filter the typical online search supports or how something like this is typically done with GraphQL.

```
{
  search(query: "query", type: REPOSITORY, first: 10) {
    repositoryCount
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Repository {
          nameWithOwner
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

I'm almost guessing this isn't quite possible and I'm going to have to query for everything and filter on the client instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `query` parameter you can use the same format as [Github search](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-repositories/), filter language with `language:LANGUAGE` :

```
{
  search(query: "language:java", type: REPOSITORY, first: 10) {
    repositoryCount
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Repository {
          nameWithOwner
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that basically just feeds into the same search. Thank you! :)

Comment: Search only allows 1000 records, what beyond that if we have more than 1000 records?